# $I$ an ideal $\implies f(I)=I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be rings and suppose there is an ideal $I$ such that $I\subset R_1$ and $I\subset R_ 2$.

Suppose $f:R_1\to R_2$ is an homomorphism.

If $x\in I$, is it true $f(x)=x$? If don't, maybe we can have at least $f(I)=I$?

I couldn't prove it, I think is not true, someone knows some counter example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: A special case would be that if $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ and $f: R\to R$ is a homomorphism, then $f(I) = I$.

Comment: Dear @TobiasKildetoft if $f:R_1\to R_2$ is an isomorphism can we have $f(x)=x$, if $x\in I$?

Comment: We can, but we need not. See my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant if $f:R_1\to R_2$ is an isomorphism we _necessarily_ have $f(x)=x,if \in I$?

Comment: As I said, that need not be the case, as my answer shows.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I"m working on your answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more fleshed-out version of my comment: As I mentioned there, a special case would be that then any ideal of a ring would be preserved under endomorphisms of the ring.

To find an example where this fails, take for example any ring $R$ and consider $R\times R$. This has a nice automorphism which switches the two factors. Can you find an ideal not preserved by this automorphism?